# Is this function Lebesgue-integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

The following function:

$$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Lebesgue-integrable in $\Omega:=(0,1)\times(0,1)$?

My approach is to convert in polar coordinates and I don't know what would be the boundaries(I think for $\varphi=(0,\pi/2)$ but I don't have idea for $r$)and then to see if integral is finite that implies that is Lebesgue-integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert to polar coordinates, you get
$$f(r,\theta)=\frac{\cos(2\theta)}{r^2},$$
yes? Plugging into a polar integral: (since the differential is now $rdrd\theta$)
$$\int_{(0,1)^2}\frac{\cos(2\theta)}{r}drd\theta.$$
Do you expect this integral to be finite?

This question was asked recently here: [Is the function $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ lebesgue integrable in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528018/is-the-function-fx-y-fracx2-y2x2y22-lebesgue-integrable-in/1528052#1528052)